# Discolored LCD screen

Tags: monitor

I recently got a better screen for [my computer](http://paste.ubuntu.com/773556). It's an LCD versus a CRT - the ViewSonic VA902b. I'm quite satisfied with it because it's better than the CRT, but it's a little discolored. It's got exactly the same problem as [This Person](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100113112120AANG0dc), but they didn't get a good answer. I've tried to set several things with the monitor's buttons:

- Auto image adjust
- Color Adjust
- Brightness/contrast

However I'm rather a headless chicken when it comes to those things. Perhaps the amplifier or something?
 - search

Answer (score 1):

Can have many causes. But I will need more information.
Can you post a picture of how far off it is? IE is it a screen calibration problem or is it a serious error in the display/drivers/cable/videocard hardware.

Some general things you can try.

1. Check the cables and possibly test other cables and/or connection types. IE try a VGA if you use DVI.
2. Double check what drivers you are using and see if a different driver doesn't have this problem.
3. Try using screen calibration software.

Comment: Here is a photo: http://wstaw.org/m/2011/12/31/IMG_0007.JPG It's a very accurate depiction of the screen's appearance and color. Than you for your suggestions. I can only use VGA with this monitor. I will try screen calibration software at once.

Comment: Could you recommend any screen calibration software to use?

Comment: Your google is as good as mine. I haven't used any for KDE before. I only did photo editing on Windows. So for the linux distro's I didn't care too much unless it was obviously bugging me like this.

Comment: Looked at the picture now. That looks like a pretty strong color shift. It looks more like a loose cable then a calibration fault. Try fastening your cables again. And are there any alternative ways you can try to connect it?

Comment: I reconnected the VGA cable. There is no HDMI on the monitor, however my GPU has an HDMI out. If I got a VGA to HDMI adapter do you think it might work?

Comment: It's not guaranteed I suggested it as a means to isolate the problem.

Comment: OK. I have another GPU which I will also try.